# how to replace value in a string with a decimal value in java

Tags: java

Want to replace a string value with decimal value. Suppose "4" is a string value want to replace "0.5" instead of 4.
I am getting a error:

```
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
```

Here is what I tried:

```
float rename = Float.parseFloat(activ.code1);
  String str = Float.toString(rename);
  str.replaceAll("4", "0.5");
  activ.code1=str;
```

My input is "4" and I want output as "0.5". But when I give only replace like:

```
String.replace("4", "0.5");
```

It prints 0.1 instead of 0.5

Comment: Can you show us sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Input is instead of "4" I am replacing "0.5"                                                           Output is 0.5

Comment: If your String is just "4", why not just create a new String "0.5" and use it?. This looks like a XY problem

Comment: FYI: From [comment to answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096800/how-to-replace-value-in-a-string-with-a-decimal-value-in-java#comment61736973_37096854): *`activ.code1` has `"3","4","5"` values which I am replacing as `"0","0.5","1"`*

Comment: It's looks to be working fine is this what you're expecting?  http://ideone.com/j3YNTF

Comment: There is nothing here that prints anything. Can you *define* the *rule* by which this substitution is to be made? And what do you mean by a 'decimal value'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` in java is immutable and hence you would need to assign the value after replacing "4" with "0.5" like:

```
str = str.replace("4", "0.5");//use replace instead of replaceAll
```

This call would replace all the occurrence of 4 to 0.5. If there are multiple occurrence of 4 then it would replace all the occurrence.

e.g.
Input: 4444
output: 0.50.50.50.5

Comment: It is not working instead of 0.5 its printing 0.1. This was happening with replaceAll too.

Comment: yup activ.code1 has "3","4","5" values which I am replacing as "0","0.5","1"

Comment: Then that's why your call `Float.parseFloat(activ.code1);` is failing. .

Comment: @programmer `"3","4","5"` is not a floating point number, so you cannot parse that *single* text value using `parseFloat()`. Please *edit* the question and clarify, with an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), what your input is and what you want output to be.